# excel file write and read show difficulty

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, xlsxwriter

After running code i have find some problem

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
array = [0.222333333333333, 0.048150492835172518, 'a12', 'a13', 'a14']
a=[array]
print('writedata=',a)
row = 0
for col, data in enumerate(a):
workbook.close()

workbook.close()
x = pd.read_excel('arrays.xlsx')
print('readdata=',x)`
```

write read is like array

```
[0.222333333333333, 0.048150492835172518, 'a12', 'a13', 'a14']
```

but after reading that show like this

```
readdata= Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0.222333333333333, 0.04815049283517252, a12, a13, a14]
Index: []
```

how i get only that like simple answer

```
[0.222333333333333, 0.04815049283517252, a12, a13, a14]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a side effect of the precision of floating point numbers.

Excel uses [IEEE 754 Doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) to store numbers. The precision of these numbers is 16 digits whereas the number you are trying to store, 0.048150492835172518, has 17 significant digits.

You will see the same behaviour if you insert 0.048150492835172518 into a cell in Excel, save the file, close it, open it again and then copy out the number.

Comment: jmcnamara  can you solve that problem in above code.?please